# Can't focus and insert text in Java awt textbox on Eclipse Mac

Tags: java, macos, awt

When I'm running my Java application containg a Java awt textbox, I can not place my cursor in it or write text in it on my Mac. It seems that clicking or pressing a key has no effect at all. On a Windows machine, this works fine.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Please provide some code related to the problem. Where the textbox is initialized and what attributes it has is a good start.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).